# Improve This: Change button text/background onmousedown - revert onmouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I would like to see if anyone in the community can improve on this code.

GOAL: The application is full of input elements that are styled up to look like custom buttons. They are of various types e.g. 'submit', 'reset' and 'button'. When the user hits the button (i.e. clicks it with their mouse on PC or touches the screen on the right place on a touch-screen device e.g. BlackBerry) the button text and background should change to indicate the button has been pushed. The text and background should revert before the action associated with the button is executed - to indicate the button has been released.

Here is the snippet of the code that I have for my solution - can anyone see ways to improve/slim/refactor?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        RegisterJQueryFunctions();
    });
</script>
```

In an external file:

```
function RegisterJQueryFunctions() {
    $('input[type=submit], input[type=button], input[type=reset]').mousedown(function () {

        // Record the original font and BG colors so we can revert back to them in 'delight'
        var originalFont = $(this).css("color");
        var originalBG = $(this).css("background-color");

        $(this).data("originalFont", originalFont);
        $(this).data("originalBG", originalBG);

        $(this).highlightBG();
        $(this).highlightFont();
        

    });
    $('input[type=submit], input[type=button], input[type=reset]').mouseup(function () {
        $(this).revertFont();
        $(this).revertBG();
    });

    $.fn.highlightFont = function (highlightFontColor) {
        var highlightFont = highlightFontColor || "#FFFFFF"; // Defaults to white
        $(this).css("color", highlightFont);
    };

    $.fn.highlightBG = function (highlightBGColor) {
        var highlightBg = highlightBGColor || "#FF7F00"; // Defaults to orange
        $(this).css("background-color", highlightBg);
    };

    $.fn.revertFont = function () {
        var originalFont = $(this).data("originalFont");
        if (!originalFont.length)
            originalFont = "#000000"; // Defaults to black in case data attribute wasn't set properly in highlightFont

        $(this)
            .css("color", originalFont);
    };
    $.fn.revertBG = function () {
        var originalBG = $(this).data("originalBG");

        if (!originalBG.length)
            originalBG = "#FEC800"; // Defaults to orange in case data attribute wasn't set properly in highlightFont
        $(this)
            .css("background-color", originalBG);
    };
}
```

Comment: This is usually done with CSS styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do it with CSS.  If you want the pressed look to be the following CSS

```
 .pressed { color : #ffffff; background-color : #FEC800; }
```

Then your functions are simple:

```
function RegisterJQueryFunctions() {
   $('input[type=submit], input[type=button], input[type=reset]')

      .mousedown(function () { $(this).toggleClass("pressed",true); })

      .mouseup(function () { $(this).toggleClass("pressed",false);  });
}
```

You can have different pressed looks for different input types (using standard CSS selectors).

You are separating the styling from the code (always a good thing.)

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS (class), you can reduce the size of your code drastically. Secondly CSS will give the option of changing colors without altering your javascript (Themes). The sole purpose of CSS is to give look and feel to the site & for javascript, add dynamic behavior to the site.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- If you're using the same jQuery selector several times you should cache the
  first jQuery object returned and reuse it
- If you're calling several jQuery methods on the same jQuery object you can chain them
- I dislike single-use variables: if a variable is only assigned a value in one
  place *and* that value is only used in one (other) place then you don't need it
- If setting more than one value with `.data()` (or `.attr()` or in several other jQuery methods) you can do all with a single call by putting the properties in a map

So:

```
function RegisterJQueryFunctions() {
    $('input[type=submit], input[type=button], input[type=reset]').mouseup(function () {
        $(this).revertFont().revertBG();
    })
    .mousedown(function () {    
        // Record the original font and BG colors so we can revert back to them in 'delight'
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.data({"originalFont" : $this.css("color"),
                      "originalBG"   :, $this.css("background-color")
        })
        .highlightBG()
        .highlightFont();
    });

    $.fn.highlightFont = function (highlightFontColor) {
        $(this).css("color", highlightFontColor || "#FFFFFF");// Defaults to white
    };

    $.fn.highlightBG = function (highlightBGColor) {
        $(this).css("background-color", highlightBGColor || "#FF7F00";); 
    };

    $.fn.revertFont = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // Defaults to black in case data attribute wasn't set properly in highlightFont
        $this.css("color", $this.data("originalFont") || "#000000");
    };
    $.fn.revertBG = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // Defaults to orange in case data attribute wasn't set properly in highlightFont
        $this.css("background-color", $this.data("originalBG") || "#FEC800");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of the above advice, this is the solution is ended up with:

```
$('input[type=submit], input[type=button], input[type=reset]')
  .mousedown(function () { $(this).toggleClass("pressed", true); })
  .mouseup(function () { $(this).toggleClass("pressed", false); })
  .focusout(function () { $(this).toggleClass("pressed",false);  });

$('a,a>*')
  .mousedown(function () { $(this).toggleClass("pressed",true); })
  .mouseup(function () { $(this).toggleClass("pressed", false); })
  .focusout(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("pressed", false);
      $(this).children().toggleClass("pressed", false); // call explictily because some elements don't raise the 'focusout' event
      });
```